# get applescript to start android emulator on right side of screen

Tags: applescript

I set up an android emulator where if I do `android avd` and start a device an emulator of that device appears. I would like to run an apple script that will position this emulator window to a position on the monitor of my choosing. What is an example applescript code that I could use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this code from the Script Editor and watch its window move.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Script Editor"
        set position of window 1 to {4, 90}
    end tell
end tell
```

You can find the name of the process you want to control with this...

```
tell application "System Events" to return name of processes
```